# Compiling Clang on Windows

Tags: windows, llvm, clang

I followed instructions at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

I compiled latest trunk of llvm and clang with MSVC 2010. Now I can compile simple programs with Clang but when I tried to compile this program I got a lot of errors.
Here is program:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main(){ return 0; }
```

And here are some of errors:

```
In file included from hello.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\memory:987:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h:24:
In file included from H:/LLVM/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.3/include\immintrin.h:32:
In file included from H:/LLVM/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.3/include\xmmintrin.h:988:
H:/LLVM/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.3/include\emmintrin.h:1384:22: error: expected expression
  return (__m128)__in;
                     ^
H:/LLVM/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.3/include\emmintrin.h:1390:23: error: expected expression
  return (__m128i)__in;
                      ^
H:/LLVM/build/bin/Debug/../lib/clang/3.3/include\emmintrin.h:1396:23: error: expected expression
  return (__m128d)__in;
                      ^
```

Complete output from Clang: http://pastebin.com/qi87K8qr

Clang tries to use MSVC headers but it doesn't work. Maybe I should use libc++ or libstdc++ instead, but how to do that?

**Note** I'm not interested in precompiled clang binaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, clang simply does not support all of Microsoft's extended C++ syntax, and therefore cannot parse Microsoft's C++ headers which use that syntax. Not only that but Clang also doesn't have complete support for Microsoft's C++ ABI, name mangling, etc. I believe Clang on Windows works alright with C, however.

To use a different C++ standard library instead you can make clang ignore the normal header and library directories with, IIRC, `-nostdinc++` and `-nostdlib++`. Then you can tell clang the include and library directories you want to use (using `-isystem` or `-I` or whatever). However I'm not sure whether libc++ or libstdc++ work under those circumstances, since they probably depend on things that the Windows C runtime library does not have.

Answer (score 2):

Chandler Carruth [mentioned at Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/The-Care-and-Feeding-of-C-s-Dragons) that there are now [alpha builds of clang for Windows](http://llvm.org/builds/) with Visual Studio integration. Lots of stuff is broken, for example, streams (so good old hello world won't work). However, there is a lot of effort being put into making clang work on Windows, so expect it to get pretty good pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Errors were in the header supplied with clang itself. Looks like it can't handle MMX/SSE types properly. Try to add -msse -msse2 switches to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using libstdc++ and built clang using VS2012Express for desktop. The cmake string was "Visual Studio 11 Win64" and the essential dirs. are specified using -I argument.

Answer (score 0):

My guess you program could work if I used mingw headers for Windows.